# Outlook 365 (pywin32) - cannot access the body of the e-mails

Tags: python, outlook, office365, pywin32

Since we moved to the Office Semi-Annual **Enterprise** Channel, version 1908, build 11929.**20838**, I cannot access the **body** or even the **sender** of the e-mails anymore via MAPI.

**Python version:** tried   3.6.8 32-bit,  3.6.8 64-bit  and  3.8.2 32-bit.
**Pywin32 version:** tried  228  and  227

I am wondering why this is happening, since it still works fine on previous versions of Office (not Enterprise).

## === Code example ===

```
import win32com.client

def checkOutlookInbox():
    account = 'MyEmail@example.com'
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.Folders(account).Folders("Inbox")
    messages = inbox.Items

    for message in messages:
        msg = message.body
        sender = message.Sender
        print(sender)
        print(msg)
```

## === Output (error) ===

File "C:\Python36-32Bit\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in **getattr**
ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)

===

Any ideas why this is happening on this specific Office version?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are not using MAPI - this is Outlook Object Model.
Secondly, are you ure you only have mail item objects in the Inbox, and not report items (NDRs) or meeting requests/updates?

Comment: You are right, it's OOM. Not MAPI. By the way, yes, I am sure I have only e-mail objects. The application is being used for over a year and as mentioned, it's still works on previous versions of Outlook (previous build and not "Enterprise" version) with the very same code.

Comment: Does it work if you avoid touching the Sender and Body properties and only access a property like Subject?

Comment: Yes, it does. Actually I still can access the Subject, among a few properties of e-mails. But the Sender and Body provide the said error. Except when I run the code over a previous build. Then I am able to access all properties.

Comment: Then this is an indication that you are running into the security patch - you need to either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi)  or Redemption (any language) or ensure that the client machine has up-to-date antivirus app installed.